# Difference between express favicon and rel icon in HTML

Tags: express, favicon

What is the difference between using the middleware `static-favicon` and adding this in the `head` tag?

```
<img href='/images/icon.jpg' rel='icon'>
```

Comment: honestly it looks to be a caching difference... `static-favicon` which now looks to be moved to `serve-favicon` is just a caching system specifically designed to cache the `favicon.ico` item from your servers once set. This will allow the browser to skip the searching of a favicon and potentially load faster if it doesn't find it. It is possible for sites to not have a favicon and some people believe it makes a site slower because it is designed to be found in different places at times.

Comment: So is `caching` the only difference between the two?

Comment: I can't say 100%, but that is what it pretty much claims to achieve. I'm not sure of your exact goal, but it is very likely it will be something that isn't super useful. When you do the `link` to the favicon it doesn't always search if it has found it again depending on browser. Chrome uses caching on most things and I believe the favicon is one of them. I would look into this a bit more, but it is hard to say without knowing your goals on this.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment posted by [Cayce K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547515/cayce-k):

> honestly it looks to be a caching difference... static-favicon which
>   now looks to be moved to serve-favicon is just a caching system
>   specifically designed to cache the favicon.ico item from your servers
>   once set. This will allow the browser to skip the searching of a
>   favicon and potentially load faster if it doesn't find it. It is
>   possible for sites to not have a favicon and some people believe it
>   makes a site slower because it is designed to be found in different
>   places at times